# Page not found (404) at /user_signup in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

Getting 404 error on signup and some more URLs. /login, /logout, /admin is working perfectly. I'm making a web app that lets a user login, logout, search a flight, book a flight and view the bookings made.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.home, name='home'),
  path('search_flights/', views.search_flights, name='search_flights'),
  path('book_flight/<int:flight_id>/', views.book_flight, name='book_flight'),
  path('my_bookings/', views.my_bookings, name='my_bookings'),
  path('login/', views.user_signup, name='login'),
  path('signup/', views.user_signup, name='signup'),]
```

views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm, UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import Flight, Booking
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .forms import SignUpForm, SignInForm, EditProfileForm


def home(request):
   flights = Flight.objects.all()
   return render(request, 'home.html', {'flights': flights})

@login_required
def search_flights(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       date = request.POST.get('date')
       time = request.POST.get('time')
       flights = Flight.objects.filter(date=date, time=time)
       return render(request, 'search_flights.html', {'flights': flights})
   return render(request, 'search_flights.html')
       

@login_required
def book_flight(request, flight_id):
   flight = Flight.objects.get(id=flight_id)
   if request.method == 'POST':
       # Check if seats are available
       if flight.seats_available() > 0:
           # Book the ticket
           booking = Booking.objects.create(flight=flight, user=request.user)
           return redirect('my_bookings')
       else:
           # Show error message
           return render(request, 'book_flight.html', {'flight': flight, 'error': 'No seats available.'})
   return render(request, 'book_flight.html', {'flight': flight})

@login_required
def my_bookings(request):
   bookings = Booking.objects.filter(user=request.user)
   return render(request, 'my_bookings.html', {'bookings': bookings})

def user_login(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
           password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
           user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
           if user is not None:
               login(request, user)
               return redirect('home')
   else:
       form = AuthenticationForm()
   return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})

def user_signup(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           user = form.save()
           login(request, user)
           return redirect('home')
   else:
       form = UserCreationForm()
   return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

Any idea what might be going wrong? I am skeptical about the placement of the templates folder, but changing that introduced the Template doesn't exist error.

main urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'admin/',admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('app/', include('app.urls')),
    path('',include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'),name='home')]
```

Directory structure-

```
flight
└─ flight_booking
   ├─ app
   │  ├─ admin.py
   │  ├─ apps.py
   │  ├─ migrations
   │  │  ├─ 0001_initial.py
   │  │  ├─ __init__.py
   │  │  └─ __pycache__
   │  │     ├─ 0001_initial.cpython-39.pyc
   │  │     └─ __init__.cpython-39.pyc
   │  ├─ models.py
   │  ├─ templates
   │  │  └─ app
   │  │     ├─ book_flight.html
   │  │     └─ search_fights.html
   │  ├─ tests.py
   │  ├─ urls.py
   │  ├─ views.py
   │  ├─ __init__.py
   │  └─ __pycache__
   │     ├─ admin.cpython-39.pyc
   │     ├─ apps.cpython-39.pyc
   │     ├─ forms.cpython-39.pyc
   │     ├─ models.cpython-39.pyc
   │     ├─ urls.cpython-39.pyc
   │     ├─ views.cpython-39.pyc
   │     └─ __init__.cpython-39.pyc
   ├─ db.sqlite3
   ├─ flight_booking
   │  ├─ asgi.py
   │  ├─ settings.py
   │  ├─ urls.py
   │  ├─ views.py
   │  ├─ wsgi.py
   │  ├─ __init__.py
   │  └─ __pycache__
   │     ├─ settings.cpython-39.pyc
   │     ├─ urls.cpython-39.pyc
   │     ├─ views.cpython-39.pyc
   │     ├─ wsgi.cpython-39.pyc
   │     └─ __init__.cpython-39.pyc
   ├─ manage.py
   └─ templates
      ├─ base.html
      ├─ home.html
      └─ registration
         ├─ login.html
         └─ signup.html
```

Comment: Can you provide your main urls.py and directory structure? :)

Comment: Sure, I've added that in the question, please have a look

Comment: You don't have `/user_signup` url pattern. It's a name of the `user_signup` view which can be _invoked_ via urls `/login` and `/signup` as you defined in urls.py. Please show full error traceback and part of the template which contains hyperlink to `/user_signup` URL.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are using the HTML files you actually created,
try changing the return statement of your `user_signup` view to this:

`return render(request, 'app/registration/signup.html', {'form': form})`

Comment: tried that, still no luck

Comment: Apologies, its that I noticed your title again, the 404 error is on path '/user_signup.' I'm not sure why you are being redirected to that I'm guessing its a base Django auth template. Please try accessing 'http:127.0.0.1/app/signup' and see if you get the right page with the template path above.

Comment: yes that worked! thank you so much. I moved the registrations folder to the main templates folder. But I'm still not able to render 'book_flight.html' and 'search_flight.html'. I've updated the directory structure in the question

Comment: Glad that worked, so that's because you have put your templates in the templates subfolder 'app'. So when you return those templates using the full subdirectory within the app templates folder, so you need to specify 'app/book_flight.html', etc. This is true for any other apps you may create as well, technically you don't even need the 'app' folder inside your templates folder but its good practice if you have multiple apps so there are no naming conflicts between apps.