# TemplateDoesNotExist at /app/search_flights/ in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm making a web app that lets a user login, logout, search a flight, book a flight and view the bookings made. For some reason the 'search_flights/html' is not being rendered or Django's not being able to find it. I spent a lot of time trying to debug it but with no luck.

Project directory (I've included search_flights.html both in the root templates folder as well as the app templates folder as of now to see if changing anything will work, but it didn't)

```
flight
└─ flight_booking
   ├─ app
   │  ├─ admin.py
   │  ├─ apps.py
   │  ├─ migrations
   │  │  ├─ 0001_initial.py
   │  │  ├─ __init__.py
   │  │  └─ __pycache__
   │  │     ├─ 0001_initial.cpython-39.pyc
   │  │     └─ __init__.cpython-39.pyc
   │  ├─ models.py
   │  ├─ templates
   │  │  ├─ app
   │  │  │  ├─ book_flight.html
   │  │  │  └─ search_fights.html
   │  │  └─ base.html
   │  ├─ tests.py
   │  ├─ urls.py
   │  ├─ views.py
   │  ├─ __init__.py
   │  └─ __pycache__
   │     ├─ admin.cpython-39.pyc
   │     ├─ apps.cpython-39.pyc
   │     ├─ forms.cpython-39.pyc
   │     ├─ models.cpython-39.pyc
   │     ├─ urls.cpython-39.pyc
   │     ├─ views.cpython-39.pyc
   │     └─ __init__.cpython-39.pyc
   ├─ db.sqlite3
   ├─ flight_booking
   │  ├─ asgi.py
   │  ├─ settings.py
   │  ├─ urls.py
   │  ├─ views.py
   │  ├─ wsgi.py
   │  ├─ __init__.py
   │  └─ __pycache__
   │     ├─ settings.cpython-39.pyc
   │     ├─ urls.cpython-39.pyc
   │     ├─ views.cpython-39.pyc
   │     ├─ wsgi.cpython-39.pyc
   │     └─ __init__.cpython-39.pyc
   ├─ manage.py
   └─ templates
      ├─ app
      │  └─ search_fights.html
      ├─ home.html
      └─ registration
         ├─ login.html
         └─ signup.html
```

search_flights view

```py
def search_flights(request):
    flights = Flight.objects.none() # initialize flights with an empty queryset
    if request.method == 'POST':
        date = request.POST.get('date')
        time = request.POST.get('time')
        flights = Flight.objects.filter(date=date, time=time)
    return render(request, 'app/search_flights.html', {'flights': flights})
```

search_flights.html

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Search Flights</h1>

  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div>
      <label for="id_date">Date:</label>
      <input type="date" id="id_date" name="date">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="id_time">Time:</label>
      <input type="time" id="id_time" name="time">
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>

  {% if flights %}
    <h2>Flights:</h2>
    <ul>
    {% for flight in flights %}
      <li>
        <a href="{% url 'book_flight' flight.id %}">{{ flight }}</a>
        ({{ flight.date|date:"d M Y" }}, {{ flight.time|time:"H:i" }})
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Please help me debug this issue. Thank you!

I tried changing the location of the template but it is giving the same error.

Comment: Are you running locally with `DEBUG = True` or is it a production issue?

Comment: running locally

Comment: There is a typo, your filename is `search_fights.html`.

Comment: So many troubles in the same homework https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76057743/page-not-found-404-at-user-signup-in-django#comment134138953_76057743 And same wish to both of you: please stop posting `__pycache__` folder contents - they are useless here. And getting them back after someone cleaned up your post for readability does not increase chances to get the answer. Also in both question it does not seem that OP made much effort to solve the issue.

Comment: Good spot @Niko - I totally missed that :D